# Using GNU C++ built library in VS C++ project

Tags: visual-c++, dll, gnu

I'm trying to implement an open source library that is built using the GNU compiler. (namely, this: https://github.com/mjwybrow/adaptagrams )

I've tried opening and building that source code using VSC++ 6, but it results in over a thousand errors due to the strict nature of the VS compiler I guess. And rather then go through every error and try fix it myself, I was wondering if it's possible to just include the .lib if it is built with the GNU compiler?

EDIT:

Included in the source code linked above is an autogen.sh file.

```
mkdir -p m4
autoreconf --install --verbose
automake -a --add-missing
./configure
make
```

Running that with Cygwin results in a few .a library files to be created, which are unusable in VS. **Is it ok to just rename these to .lib files?**

I've found some stuff online about how to use GCC and create a DLL, but my problem is that I don't know enough about the GNU compiler or makefiles, or the source code in general to be able to change it right now.

Does anybody have any clues on what exactly I'd need to change to get it right? Or even better, has anyone created a DLL using this source code already that would be able to pass it on to me, or let me know what I have to do?

Or could anyone point me towards a similar library that would be compatible with visual studio?

Comment: why vsc++ 6? Its sooooo outdated and its c++ implementation is very buggy and not conforming in many places. Use a more up to date version of Visual Studio. There are free versions available.

Comment: It's just what the application was built in when I joined the company. Work has started to update the VS version, but it's such a big application...

Answer (score 0):

No; you can however build the .dll file with gcc and use the .dll from msvc (with either a hand-crafted include file or a properly formatted one from the beginning, with platform specific import/export macros on top).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've managed to finally build the library using CygWin, but it builds the library using litool, which results in a .la library file - unusable in MSVC. I found some stuff online that shows how to build a dll. My problem now however is that I am not very familiar with the GCC compiler and the MakeFiles that are used. I'll edit my post with the more details to this problem...